# Algorithm to minimize $\operatorname{tr}(PAP^TB)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, combinatorial-optimization, traces

Let say I have two $n$ x $n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ where all elements are real positive values. I want to find some $n$ x $n$ permutation matrix $P$ such that $\operatorname{tr}(P A P ^T B)$ is minimized. Does there exist such an algorithm or technique?

Comment: How large a value of n do you need to solve?

Comment: This looks like the [quadratic assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_assignment_problem) (QAP).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is NP-hard.

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of an $n$-cycle plus the all-ones matrix and $B$ the adjacency matrix of a graph $G$ plus the all-ones matrix.

Then, if $G$ has a Hamiltonian cycle, the maximum trace is achieved when the elements of $PAP^T$ with value $2$ corresponds to a Hamiltonian cycle in $G$. Since finding Hamiltonian cycles is NP-hard, your problem is NP-hard.

Comment: Oh no! I was afraid this was the case. Your proof is very elegant so I can’t even argue with it. My only criticism is that my question was about minimizing not maximizing, but your general proof would still work in the minimizing case if you set $A$ equal to 1 - (n adjacency matrix) instead